# Is using dropbox (or similar) instead of a simple server a valid solution?

Tags: cloud, synchronization, dropbox

I'm writing a small business application and I need to write a simple server for receiving and sending small ( < 1kb per request) amounts of data (text data).

***Basically I have to sync some files from server side and some files from client side.
Could I just leave all the syncing to a cloud based service (dropbox, ...) ?***

Server side will modify its files about 5 times per day.
Clients will modify their files 20 times per hour.
There will be max 200 clients.
All the files will be text files with less than 100kb in size.

(if this is a possible solution I would like to know the maximum number of clients that such a solution would allow)

Thank you for your time and answer.

***EDIT:***
I am wondering if this solution would perform worse then a dedicated asynchronous server. And if there are any other possible problems with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds possible.

You haven't identified any specific concerns, so no further comment is possible. Why not try it and see?

**Edit:**

Regarding performance vs your hypothetical dedicated server - what's the performance of your hypothetical server? The question you need to address is whether dropbox is *fast enough*.

As to other disadvantages - your client will need to pay for dropbox, and your client will need to pay attention to dropbox service updates to know when this facility is going to not work. You will also need to make sure that dropbox meets your client's security and privacy needs, and they will need to monitor updates to e.g. terms of service that could compromise that.